# To show Pop-up Before starting the Protractor E2E Test

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, karma-runner

I am writing Angular E2E test cases using Protractor. I have Almost completed 30-40 protractor test. To make test more Interactive I want to Show Popup Which show the Title of the Test i.e 1. This test is regarding to the Sorting 2. This Test is regarding to the Filtering and so on is this Possible ...??? If yes Please suggest me some approach....

Answer (score -1):

You could use toastr. Its a javascript library.

http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/

I'm not very sure how toastr would work in tandem with protractor.You could give it a try.

Comment: Ok I will try ..Thanks